# How to retrieve diagonal of String matrix in separate list?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to retrieve diagonal of String Matrix into separate list. Please help me. I spend whole day on it. but no success.

Two Dimensional Array Structure:

```
Matrix{{"Toyata","Fortuner","Price", "tuesday", "deliver", "Working"},
        { "Ford","Classic ","Price", "Wedday", "Not Deliver", "Working"}, 
         {"Tata","Jaguar","Price", "Satday", "deliver", "Working" }
        {"Farari","etc","Price", "sunday", "deliver", "NotWorking" }
```

I want to retrieve 1st and 3rd row from be above matrix. ie

```
{"Toyata","Fortuner","Price", "tuesday", "deliver", "Working"},
   {"Tata","Jaguar","Price", "Satday", "deliver", "Working" }
```

Here is my code :

```
    public  Object[][] geCodes(){
   Object [][] Matrix{
               {"Toyata","Fortuner","Price", "tuesday", "deliver", "Working"},
                { "Ford","Classic ","Price", "Wedday", "Not Deliver", "Working"}, 
                 {"Tata","Jaguar","Price", "Satday", "deliver", "Working" }
                {"Farari","etc","Price", "sunday", "deliver", "NotWorking" }};
     Object  Diagonal1=null;
     List<Object> che= new LinkedList<Object>();
        for (int i = 0, j =0; i< matrix.length && j < matrix[0].length; i++, j++) {
             Diagonal1=   matrix[i][j];
             che.add(Diagonal1);

     }
        System.out.println("*******"+che);
                return matrix;

    }
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) also: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what is the output that you are getting?

Comment: So do you want a diagonal or 1st and 3rd row?

Comment: Hi Ivan , Thanks for quick reply , I want 1st and 3rd row. which are basically  in diagonal.

Comment: Hi Garima, I am getting output as {Toyota, 'Classic', 'Price ', Sunday}

Comment: Why are you using `Object` instead of `String` ? To get a row from a multidimensional array simply do `String[] row = matrix[1]`. Diagonal means something completely different to me.

Comment: actually, data retrieve from Excel and store it  in Matrix ,  If data-structure change , I worried String will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saying what you think you are saying. Diagonal means first element of first row, second element of second row.... last element of last row.

You make a single loop and get the matrix[i][i] position. You don't need "i" and "j" since they will be the same.

If you want to get the first and theird row, then you do just that.

```
Object[][] matrix2 = new Object[2][6];
matrix2[0] = Matrix[0];
matrix2[1] = Matrix[2];
```

Your code:

```
public  Object[][] geCodes(){
    Object [][] Matrix{
        {"Toyata","Fortuner","Price", "tuesday", "deliver", "Working"},
        {"Ford","Classic ","Price", "Wedday", "Not Deliver", "Working"}, 
        {"Tata","Jaguar","Price", "Satday", "deliver", "Working" }
        {"Farari","etc","Price", "sunday", "deliver", "NotWorking" }};


    Object[][] Diagonal1= new Object[2][6];
    Diagonal1[0] = Matrix[0];
    Diagonal1[1] = Matrix[2];

    return matrix; // I don't know why you are returning matrix, 
                   // you probably should be returning the new array, Diagonal1

}
```

You really should use Strings instead of Objects.

Comment: Thanks Johan , This is what I am exactly looking for.    return matrix is by mistakenly left.

Answer (score -1):

I don't really get if you want the diagonal or first and third but here is an example:

```
    String[][] matrixStart = {
                {"Toyata", "Fortuner", "Price", "tuesday", "deliver", "Working"},
                {"Ford", "Classic", "Price", "Wedday", "Not Deliver", "Working"},
                {"Tata", "Jaguar", "Price", "Satday", "deliver", "Working"},
                {"Farari", "etc", "Price", "sunday", "deliver", "NotWorking"}};
    List<String[]> matrixEnd = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < matrixStart.length; i++)
        {
            if(i == 1 || i == 3)
            {
            matrixEnd.add(matrixStart[i]);
            }
        }

    // Printing what's in your matrixEnd
    System.out.println("MatrixEnd :");
    String sysout;
    for(String[] line: matrixEnd)
    {
        sysout = "";
        for(String element: line)
        {
            sysout += element + ", ";
        }
        System.out.println("[" + sysout.substring(0, sysout.length() - 2) + "]");
    }
```

In the end you'll get something like :

```
MatrixEnd :
    [Ford, Classic, Price, Wedday, Not Deliver, Working]
    [Farari, etc, Price, sunday, deliver, NotWorking]
```

Also, you should use String instead of Objects and name your variables with lowercase, finally printing "che" will not print what's inside but only the reference, unless you overrode toString() for LinkedList.